# How do I query in ElementTree as in Xpath?

Tags: python, xpath, elementtree

This is a sample query I might do in PHP:

```
foreach(steps as step)
{
  areT_eles = xpath->query(t_eleQuery, step)
}
```

Now in python:

```
for step in index steps:
  areT_eles = ?!?!?!?!!??!?!!??!!
```

I tried this:

```
for step in index steps:
  areT_eles = xpath.query(t_eleQuery, step)
```

It didn't work.  I've only imported Elementtree from `xml.etree.ElementTree`, though.

The most official page I was able to find on `xpath` in `elementtree` actually didn't have any documentation or examples....  And we all know how horribly bad Python official's tutorials are.  So, I'm also looking for a good resource.

Comment: Python's tutorials are not so "horribly bad" that they'll tell you to write `foreach` when you mean `for`.

Comment: @larsmans True, but they are much worse than that in other ways.  If you want me to scratch that line, that's fine.  If the community doesn't hear the outcry, though, nothing will change.  I don't want that.  I append it to all my python questions on all sites I post on.  Really, it's the people who write and edit the docs....  They don't care.

Comment: I don't find that a very constructive attitude. When a tutorial is unclear to you, contact its authors or the relevant mailing list. The Python community is, in my experience, a very helpful crowd and tolerant to newcomers, as long as you don't approach them in a hostile manner.

Comment: @larsmans They should appreciate feedback either way.  Python official's feedback system is convoluted.  I'm not saying the community is bad.  That isn't true.  The tutorials are junk, though.  The authors openly state their assumption that readers have an extended academic history in programming, but the advertising calls it the simple, everyman's language.  It's a grotesque contradiction.  The authors should take a 101 class in modern education theory, or on writing.  It will get them further with their readers than all their years learning to program combined.  Across the board, they're bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have [LXML](http://lxml.de), the high-performance, full-featured version of ElementTree, installed you can use XPath as follows:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> xml = """<ham><spam>Hello!</spam> <spam>Goodbye!</spam></ham>"""
>>> tree.xpath("//spam/text()")
['Hello!', 'Goodbye!']
```

I can recommend LXML for all your Python XML needs; it's fast and Pythonic.

Comment: Yes, I've confirmed that.  Adding 'step' as a second argument also works.  Thank you.